# whitespace in the name of the variable, use of group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this code :

```
db_enr %>%
    group_by('PCR ATLU') %>%
    summary (n = (n), mean = mean(delta_time) )
```

The name of the variable was extracted with readr (read_csv)

'PCR ATLU' (with a whitespace in the middle, for which i must add '' in my variable) has two value : Pos or Neg.

This return me a tibble 1x6 :

```
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  `"PCR ATLU :"`     n  mean
  <chr>                <int> <dbl>
1 PCR ATLU :       414  15.7
```

I want the number and the mean for each group of "PCR ATLU".

I have try with backtick in place of apostrophe or quotation mark, and it returns me this error :

```
Erreur : Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `PCR ATLU` is not found.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Backticks are the correct solution.  So, are you sure that `db_enr` contains a column named `PCR ATLU`?  Perhaps a `dput()` would help?

Comment: OK, right. The ":" has gone during the copy/past. You're right, the backticks were the good solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks:

```r
db_enr %>%
    group_by(`PCR ATLU`) %>%
    summary (n = (n), mean = mean(delta_time) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use janitor::clean_names() on your dataframe to change all the columns names and make easier to code.